# Where did I go wrong with this integration?

Tags: probability, integration

Calculate $E\!\left[X^2\right]$ with $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}$ with $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Well $f_X$ is symmetric about $0$ so this is the same as

\begin{equation*}
E\!\left[X^2\right] = 2 \int_0^\infty\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}dx.
\end{equation*} 
Let $u = x^2/2$. Then our equation becomes
\begin{equation*}
2\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \int_0^\infty ue^{-u}du =
2\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \big(1 \big)
\end{equation*} 
Where did I make an egregious error? It's probably obvious but I just don't see where I made the mistake.

Comment: Where did the $du$ come from?  $du = x dx$.

Comment: @SpamIAm Oh man I goofed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $u = x^2/2$, then $du = x \, dx = \sqrt{2u} \, dx$, consequently $$x^2 e^{-x^2/2} \, dx = \frac{2u e^{-u}}{\sqrt{2u}} \, du.$$

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out $du=\sqrt{2u}\,dx$ so we actually have

\begin{align*}
\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_0^\infty 2ue^{-u} \big(2u)^{-1/2}du &= \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^\infty u^{1/2}e^{-u} du\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\Gamma(3/2)\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\big(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\big)\\
&=1
\end{align*}
where I've used $\Gamma(t) =\int_0^\infty u^{t-1}e^{-u} du$ and $\Gamma(\frac{3}{2})=\frac{1}{2}\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})= \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\pi}.$